# How to set text view to a string by using a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I have the code bellow which once A poem is chose from the second spinner then it should show a poem excerpt in a text view.  The excerpts are stored in the values folder under strings xml.  The problem is I am not sure how I could set the text view contents to the poem depending on what one is selected, can anyone help?

code:

```
    public class Poets extends Activity implements
OnItemSelectedListener {

  // defining variables
Spinner PoetSpinner, PoemSpinner;
String Poets[] = { "", "Robert Burns", "James Beattie",
"Duncan MacGregor Crerar" };
String Poems1[] = { "", "Tam O Shanter", "Auld Lang Syne" };
String Poems2[] = { "", "Judgement Of Paris", "The Minstrel" };
String Poems3[] = { "", "A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns",
"My Bonnie Rowan Tree" };

TextView selectedPoem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// set to fullscreen mode
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// set content view
setContentView(R.layout.poet);

initialize(); // call this method
}

public void initialize() {

// initializing items that are in the class
PoetSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoet);
PoemSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoem);
// Hide the second spinner
PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
selectedPoem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedPoem);
// setting up array adapters
//
// for each spinner
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
.createFromResource(this, R.array.poet_arrays,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
PoetSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
PoetSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

PoemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    Object poem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    selectedPoem.setText(poem.toString());
  }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
});
}

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
  long id) {
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
  switch (pos) {
  case 1:
  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.poem_arrays1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  break;
  case 2:
  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.poem_arrays2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  break;
  case 3:
  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.poem_arrays3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  break;
  default:
  // Hide the poem spinner
  PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  break;
}

if (adapter != null) {
  // Set the poem spinners content and show the spinner
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  PoemSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what part you are having trouble with? Is it the gathering the poem information from the resources or setting the text of the textview?

Comment: @BrentHronik  I am assuming that the text view set text would be setText().  But what I do not know how to do it get the poem excerpts from the string folder and into the activity/class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.insert_poem_identifier_here);
```

That sample code should do what you need, just insert your needed string resource identifier.